# HTML editor inside grid panel in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, sencha-architect

I would like to know if we can have a HTML editor column inside a grid panel. My requirement is to have an editable grid column of type 'HTML editor' so that styling is allowed while editing the cell content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have anything you want inside the editor. Make sure to keep the control over what your users are posting/creating though or you will have a security breach if you load up any HTML in those editor cells.

Demo: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8ej

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    storeId:'simpsonsStore',
    fields:['name', 'email', 'phone'],
    data:{'items':[
        {"name":"Lisa", "email":"<b>lisa@simpsons.com</b>", "phone":"555-111-1224"},
        {"name":"Bart", "email":"<i>bart@simpsons.com</i>", "phone":"555--222-1234"},
        {"name":"Homer", "email":"home@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1244"},
        {"name":"Marge", "email":"marge@simpsons.com", "phone":"555-222-1254"}
    ]},
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name', editor: 'textfield'},
        {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex:1,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },
        {header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone'}
    ],
    selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: [
        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
            clicksToEdit: 1
        })
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way we can change the xtype of a column to a component other than the ones present in architect menu. When I try to change the xtype of the column to 'htmleditor' from'textfield' I don't find 'htmleditor' option in the editor list in the architect config.

Comment: Yes, Architect will only give you the base editors for each base type. You can create your own custom field if you want: http://existdissolve.com/2012/12/extjs-4-custom-editor-for-property-grid/